Can one get secondary health-insurance to speed up referrals on an HMO
Background: USA (California if it matters)
My employer switched to a different HMO, and unlike the previous one, all referrals by my PCP must be approved by the insurance before I can schedule an appointment with a specialist.  This has twice now caused my daughter to be seen by the specialist much later than the PCP wanted.
Given that the specialist won't schedule me until my HMO approves the referral, I'm assuming this is because of the risk involved if my HMO ends up not approving the referral from my PCP.  When risk needs mitigating, I think of insurance.  However, I haven't found any insurance that covers this case.  There's supplemental insurance and gap coverage, but neither of those seem to apply here.

The problem is that many HMOs condition coverage on pre-approval. So if you go to see the doctor before the approval, your request for approval will be denied. You cannot find an insurer because there's no risk to mitigate.
You might need to talk to a healthcare attorney or an advocacy group that have enough clout to pressure the HMO into changing their processes, but more likely than not these processes is what allows them to compete for your employer's business to begin with.
My experience with the (incredibly insane) US healthcare system is that most, if not all, employers have at least two plan options - HMO and EPO/PPO. So during the next open enrollment - switch. While the other plan may be more expensive, it comes with the benefit of it not being an HMO (which requires to have a PCP referral for specialist visits).
You can also raise an issue with the CA Dept. of Insurance if you think the problem leads to a significantly diminished care.
